# How to rewrite multiple else conditions in c#

Tags: c#

I've seen this topic somewhere on SO before, but cannot find it. What is the best way to avoid using this structure:

```
if (condition)
{
  if (condition2)
  {
    do();
  }
  else
  {
    myVar="test";
  }
}
else
{
   myVar="test";
}
```

Comment: What about switch/case instead ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (condition && condition2)
{
    do();
}
else 
{
    myVar="test";
}
```

Comment: I would upvote this, but I cannot endorse removing the braces

Comment: @AdamRobinson okay, here are your braces :]

Answer (score 1):

```
if (condition && condition2)
{
  do();
}
else
{
  other();
}
```

Comment: It should be `condition && condition2` and you're missing `else`.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your "structure". Write whatever is easiest to understand - especially for someone else seeing your code for the first time?

You could alternatively have written:

```
if(condition && condition2)
{
    do();
}
else
{
   myVar="test";
}
```

Comment: In this particular case he does not need the second `else` as it is the same declaration `myVar = "test";`...

Comment: Yeah - I realized that as soon as I posted. I read it quickly enough that I assumed he was setting the variable to two different values, which I didn't catch on my copy/paste job until after I submitted the answer.